# CFFI Backend not found Azure functions

Tags: python, azure-functions

Trying to deploy an azure python function from an Azure DevOps pipeline. The function gives the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named _cffi_backend

The interpreter is correct.
This is my `requirements.txt`

```
azure-functions
requests==2.26.0
cffi==1.14.5
azure-storage-blob==12.9.0
```

After having trying numerous variations, this is the final bash script I m using

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
python -m venv funcenv
source funcenv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" --no-cache-dir cffi
```

Comment: If you need to install anything to the os ie `apt-get install` then it's got to be in a dockerized app in a premium function account.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using an Azure Devops pipeline to deploy your function with cffi package, You can directly use ubuntu-latest or Linux agent to install your packages and then include them in your function code directory while deployment like below:-

I installed the required libraries like below:-

**YAML Script:-**

```yaml
trigger:

- main

  

pool:

vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

  

steps:

- task: Bash@3

inputs:

targetType: 'inline'

script: |

sudo apt-get install libffi-dev

python -m venv funcenv

source funcenv/bin/activate

pip install --upgrade pip

pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt

OR 

pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r .siliconfunc432/requirements.txt

pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" --no-cache-dir cffi
```

**Output:-**

[image]

After running the above code you can also copy the package to your Function app directory with the code below:-

```bash
# Copy packages to function app's site-packages directory
cd siliconfunc432
mkdir -p .python_packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages
cp -r ./.python_packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/* ./.python_packages/lib/site-packages/
```

And then finally deploy your Function to Azure function app with the command below:-

```bash
func azure functionapp publish siliconfunc432 --python
```

**I also agree to @Dean MacGregor you can build a docker image and install the cffi library and reference that docker image in your function code**

Comment: 1. Cannot use YAML 2. Cannot make a docker Image. Solved it adding the libs in this answer to requirements.txt https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/20427